# How to link to external file that contains a link to the Boostrap stylesheet and another for the js files

Tags: bootstrap, joomla-3.9

I have several Joomla 3.9 websites now using Bootstrap 4x - currently v4.1.3.

In the head of the index.php file for each website is this link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and in the bottom of the index.php are these three scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous" async></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous" async></script>
```

(Note: I am using jquery-3.3.1.min.js instead of the slim version as the slim version does not include scrollTop and other animation functions)

When Bootstrap 4.1.3 is updated to the next version I would prefer not to have to go into each template and update all four links manually for each site. (Each template is different).

What I would like to do is upload two files to a subdomain, e.g. files.mydomain.co.uk, one containing the link to the stylesheet and the other containing the three scripts. I would then add links to those files in the index.php. Something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://files.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap-min-css.php">
```

which is a file containing the stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com stylesheet link

and for the three scripts just before the closing body tag:

```
<link href="https://files.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap-required.php">
```

If it worked, I'd only have to update the link once each update.
I've tried it, but (probably not surprisingly) it doesn't work.

Question 1: is what I want to do possible?

Question 2: if yes, how?

Question 3: will Joomla 4x contain all these files, anyway? If so, I can probably manage until then.

Thank you.

p.s. Can someone with the appropriate reputation please add a tag for Bootstrap 4x? Thank you.

Comment: Cdn's sometimes provide a link to the latest version rather than defining the link in the URL. Perhaps use that instead

Comment: Thanks @Lodder. I will see if that type of link is available and report back if it is or not

Comment: Apparently it's a bad idea to do so: http://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/

Comment: Thank you, again, @Lodder. It seems that Bootstrap doesn't offer this facility anyway, so I'll have to cross my fingers that Joomla 4x will include these files in its core when it's launched. I think you should put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it as such. Thank you.

Comment: Being one of the old developers for Joomla 4 but still actively looking over it's development, I can tell you for sure that Joomla 4 **will** ship with jQuery 3 and Bootstrap 4. jQuery won't actually be used in core but will still be shipped for its users.

Comment: Thanks again @Lodder. Hopefully it will not be the slim.min version of jQuery 3.

Comment: Don't worry it won't be the slim version. That will break too many websites

Comment: Phew. Thanks again. Would like to combine your above comments as an answer that I can accept?

Comment: Thanks also to @mickmackusa for adding the twitter-bootstrap-4 tag.